# VBA - Filter subform on unbound field in form

Tags: vba, filter, subform

I am passing a value from a lookup form to another form.  The value shows in an unbound field on the form (works great).  I also want the subform to be filtered by what is in this unbound field.  So, for example, I pick 2016 on my lookup form.  It brings up another form, enters the value 2016 into an unbound field called yearvar.  I cannot get it to filter what's in the subform.  Here's my code that's not working:

```
yearvar.Value = Me.OpenArgs 'Enters year from lookup form into field call yearvar
Forms!frmEthEntCatYr.frmEthEntCatSubCatYr.Form.Filter = "[EthYear]= " & Chr(34) & Forms!frmEthEntCatYr.yearvar & Chr(34)
```

Form name is frmEthEntCatYr.  Subform name is frmEthEntCatSubCatYr.  Unbound field on form is called Yearvar.  Field on subform that I want to filter is called EthYear.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What data type is EthYear?  You can build a SQL Statement Rowsource linking to this field also, then use Requery to update, also you may need to refresh the form

Comment: It's just a text field.  Explain the rest of your message please.  Thanks!

Comment: In the database table, is it Text, or number? google the rest, it will be clearer on the net.

Comment: EthYear is a text field in the table, too.  I was not asking how to format the SQL Statement Rowsource.  I just wanted to know the reasoning of why that would work and my code didn't.  I was in a hurry, and maybe didn't word it right.  Please be gentle with your ratings - some of us really do search for answers before we come here.  I love this website - it helps me connect with others who code and know what I'm talking about.  Sometimes we just have dah moments and need to brainstorm with another intelligent person. I really do appreciate your suggestions, and will give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved and it was an easy fix (thanks to someone helping me with my dah moment).  I had originally tried to link the main form and subform using the Subform field linker wizard, but the unbound field was not showing (yearvar) in the Master Fields dropdowns in the Link wizard. Someone suggested just putting it in the Property Sheet - in Link Master fields, I typed yearvar and in Link Child Fields, I typed Ethyear.  Works perfectly now.  Lesson of the day for me: sometimes the wizards do not do what we want them to do, and you have to do it the manual way.  And I didn't even have to write code to do this!